# Entaglement and causality violation. Devices that detect pure states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, causality, imaging

I have not seen a similar question to mine on the site. Please forgive me if there is any.
When I studied quantum mechanics and the entanglement phenomenon, I was told that, although when one wave function collapses, so does the other **immediately**, this has no physical consequences, in the sense observers would still have to communicate through ''classical'' channels that share information at the speed of light, hence causality is never broken.

However, I was wondering: If a device that detected only pure states existed, then we could place one of the entangled particles inside, and let another person measure the entangled property(ies) of the other particle.
According to my knowledge regarding entanglement, the moment the wave function of the particle outside the box collapsed, this would make the wave function of the other particle (the one inside our device) collapse as well. Therefore, it would be possible for us to get information about the both particles faster than the speed of light (say the property is the spin along one axis and the device has a bulb which turns light or red according whether the value is up or down).

I think that, before asking about the consequences this might have, it is better to discuss whether such a device can exist or not, in terms of Physics (of course we are far away in terms of technology).

**Question.** Is there any physical reason for which a device that only detects pure states **without** making the wave function collapse cannot exist?

Comment: If a perfect measurement leaves a wavefunction intact, this violates the no cloning theorem. The part about removing a device's ability to measure mixed states makes this question even weirder.

Comment: @ConnorBehan The idea is not to measure but ''detect''. I do not know if that really makes sense. I only want my device to ''react'' to pure states, but not by measuring. That might not be possible, of course; thus my question. I did not know about the no-cloning theorem. I do not know what a perfect measurement scheme is. I am happy to drop this property if that does not affect the behaviour of my device.